# Handler doesn't take effect after I close and light the screen or back after changing to other applicaton

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, handler

Handler doesn't take effect after I close and light the screen or back after changing to other applicaton.
I use a listview and want it refresh every 3 seconds by using handler.When I first start the activity,it works well.But when I close the screen and then back to the activity,or when I change to an other application and then back to this application,the handler doesn't work at all.
The code which I write is below:

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment
@Override
    public void onStart() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
        super.onStart();
    }
```

And when I back to the application,the method of "onstart" can be  executed,but handler doesn't take effect .

Comment: post your code, for Handler and Runnable action.
to refresh every 3 seconds, you should use 


private static final int START_TIME = 0/* start immediatly */, TIME = 3000; //every 3 seconds
    
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(mRunnable, START_TIME, TIME);

Comment: @juliendumortier the runnable "cannot be cast to java.util.TimerTask".Must I write an other timetask? I also very curious about that why the handler can't take effect

Comment: sorry, 
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
public void run() { 
//code of your runnable
}
}, START_TIME, TIME);

Comment: @juliendumortier That's cool~ Thank you